# Set shader input from custom property of Material (not Object custom property)

Tags: materials, shader-nodes, custom-attributes

My goal is to work around the limitation of linked overrides that don't yet work for Materials.

I am able to use an [*object* custom property](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/176235/per-object-custom-properties-in-shaders) to set the color in shaders.  But I will have complex objects with many different materials assigned to various vertices.  An example would be to control eye color, hair color and skin tone color in a character.  So I would like to segregate these controls into Custom Properties on the Material level.

[image]

How do I obtain access to a Material Custom Property that is a color?  Is there a simpler way than this [driver approach](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/194229/111042) where I have to edit R,G and B drivers?

Comment: It's not possible. You can drive a custom property on the object level with this property, but that defeats the purpose of having a custom property on the material.